# JetBrains rider: how to attach to processes running as root

Tags: editor

Just wondering what's the best way to attach to a process running under root account. I've thought about running rider from the cmd with sudo, but it's not a good idea because it looses all my regular user's settings and keys.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `sudo` or `sudo -H` ?  What settings and keys are you concerned about losing?

Comment: I was using just sudo (sorry, Linux beginner here). The problem is that when I run sudo rider, I can't use the configurations of my regular user account...

Comment: Yes, but which ones specifically?

Comment: All of them...from themes to lics, it's just like opening the IDE for the 1st time (which makes sense because it hasn't been run under root yet).